# display: webkit-flex Pushes inline-block div to next line in Safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I´m trying to learn HTML/CSS and find that when I add 
display: -webkit-flex; to the CSS, the last div in the nav is pushed to the next line. When I disable flex box by simply deleting the line the div jumps back up to the (inline-block) nav. I'm currently testing in safari

The page looks as it should in Firefox, though not in Safari, any suggestions as to why?

Here's the code:

```
<body>
    <header> 
        <div class="logo"> 
            <h1>Guitar site</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div class="leftMenu">
                <a href="index.html" class="menuButton">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="centerMenu">
                <div>
                    <a href="beginner.html" class="link">Beginner</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="advanced.html" class="link">Advanced</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="tips.html" class="link">Tips</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightMenu">
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>  
    </header>
    <h1> test</h1>
</body>
```

This is the all the CSS I've written, there is also a CSS reset section that I haven't included.

```
.leftMenu,
.rightMenu,
.centerMenu {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: solid .1em;
    display: -webkit-flex;
}

.leftMenu,
.rightMenu {
    background-color: #454ed6;
    height: 2em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    width: 17.5%;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
}

.leftMenu {
    float: left;
}


.rightMenu {
    float: right;
}

.centerMenu a {
    display: block;
    height: 2em;
}

.centerMenu  {
    width: 65%;
    height: 6em;
    background-color: #86acbe;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: you must use  `display:-webkit-flex` for parent elements. Also use a standard format which is `display:flex`. if targeting older safari version use `display: -webkit-box;`  check demo http://jsbin.com/silolomiqe/1/edit works perfect in chrome and in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea behind the flex layout is to give the container the ability to alter its items' width/height (and order) to best fill the available space.

So the main container in your case is `nav` element; and you have to define `display:flex` property for `nav` element. And your navigation HTML structure is not in proper format.

Check the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/silolomiqe/1/edit) and here is your modified CSS Code.

```css
nav{display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-box; /*for older safari version*/
  display: flex;}

.leftMenu,
.rightMenu,
.centerMenu {
    text-align: center;
     border-bottom: solid .1em;
  justify-content: space-around;
    /*display: inline-block;
    display: -webkit-flex;*/
}

.leftMenu,
.rightMenu {
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    height: 2em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    width: 17.5%;
    /*-webkit-justify-content: space-around;*/
}

/*.leftMenu {
    float: left;
}


.rightMenu {
    float: right;
}*/

.centerMenu a {
    display: block;
    height: 2em;
}

.centerMenu  {
    width: 65%;
    height: 6em;
    background-color: #86acbe;
   /* -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;*/
}
```

```html
<header> 
    <div class="logo"> 
        <h1>Guitar site</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <div class="rightMenu">
            <a href="index.html" class="menuButton">Home</a>
        </div>
        
            <div class="rightMenu">
                <a href="beginner.html" class="link">Beginner</a>
            </div>
            <div class="rightMenu">
                <a href="advanced.html" class="link">Advanced</a>
            </div>
            <div class="rightMenu">
                <a href="tips.html" class="link">Tips</a>
            </div>
       
        <div class="rightMenu">
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </nav>  
</header>
<h1> test</h1>
```